# How to right align text?

Tags: java, formatting

I need to output something that looks like this:

[What the output should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m0D8.png)

This is what i've tried without the asterisks

```
    System.out.printf("%-15s %20s %n",name, "Gross: " + grossPay );
    System.out.printf("%20s %n Taxes(25): " + taxes);
    System.out.printf("%20s %n Net: ",netPay);
```

The grossPay, taxes, netPay are all defined else ware but they and their labels have to be right aligned and I don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594810/how-to-print-numbers-in-right-aligned-manner?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: You are printing a newline (`%n`) right after `Taxes(25)`.  Think about it.  (And if you haven’t already, read the [documentation for Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html), which is what System.out.printf uses.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
String taxes = "82.47";
System.out.printf(String.format("**%20s**", String.format("Taxes (25): %s", taxes)));


**   Taxes (25): 82.47**
```